# Probability of being less than acceptable tolerance for package size

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Consider taking a random sample of size 30 from eggs and determining a mean weight of the eggs being 52.9 g and a standard deviation of 2.25

We can assume that the weight of chicken eggs is randomly distributed and that a sample size of 30 is large enough to assume normal distribution

$X\sim N(52.9,\frac{2.25}{\sqrt30}^2)$

If wishing to package these eggs in cartons of say size 12 - what is the probability of the cartons being less than 5% of the advertised weight
Advertised weight being: $\mu n=12\mu=12\times52.9=634.8$

Distribution of a carton: $C\sim N(52.9n,\frac{2.25n}{\sqrt n}^2)$

Probability of carton being 5% less than advertised weight: $Pr(C<0.95\mu n)$

My question is - is the probability expression above [of a carton being 5% less than the mean] correct?

My understanding is that it can be simplified to:

$C_2\sim N(52.9,\frac{2.25}{\sqrt n}^2)$ & $Pr(C_2<0.95\mu)$

Comment: [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cg5j5fm7x3) - i query whether it is right as the probability does not seem to be correct

Comment: Note that 2.25 is less than 5% of 52.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to divide by the sample size (before square rooting), because the data given was the sample mean and standard devitation for the weight of *one egg*, not the total sample.   (Unless they were really small eggs.)

Thus we approximate the distribution for the weight of one egg as:
$$X\mathop{\dot\sim}\mathcal N(52.9\mathrm g, 2.25^2\mathrm g^2)$$

The sum of $n$ independent and normally distributed random variables (terms), is a normally distributed random variable whose mean is the sum of means for the terms, and variance is the sum of the variances for the terms.

$$C\sim\mathcal N(n\mu_{\small X}, n\sigma^2_{\small X})$$

Thus for a dozen-egg carton, the total egg weight will have a normal distribution of:

$$C\mathop{\dot\sim}\mathcal N(12\cdot 52.9\mathrm g, 12\cdot 2.25^2\mathrm g^2)$$

Now, if $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, the probability $\mathsf P(C\leq 0.95(12\cdot 52.9))$ will equal $$\mathsf P\left(Z\leq\dfrac{-0.05(12\cdot 52.9)}{2.25\cdot\surd 12}\right)$$

Comment: Does $g^2$ represent *square grams*?

Comment: Yes.  The units of variance are squared.